# Windows store app with Javascript or traditional web application?? For a rich interface desktop app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i know there are some articles about the differences, pros and cons between developing a web app and a winRT app, but i would like to ask you for your proffesional point of view about my personal situation, because after reading some of those papers, i´m still full of doubts.

I´m searching for the tools to develop a desktop app with these requirements:

1. Must be a "touch-first" application.
2. Its UI must have a rich and user friendly design (smartphone-like).
3. Its main job is to control some multimedia devices mainly through http or telnet (sockets or RS-232) propietary APIs, like video matrix, audio matrix, videoconference codecs, videostream codecs, IP cameras, etc.
4. It was already developped in another programming language (Netlinx),
   and it had around 20 different modules to control different devices
   or to give different user functionalities. So maybe it could result
   in a "code hell" if developing in Javascript/WinRT??

With that in mind, i´m not sure if to focus to a web app (with .NET MVC pattern, for example), so we have an HTML/CSS modern UI and at the server side, control all the communication protocols with the external devices. I think that most of the touch gestures events could be handled in web and we´d have a clean application with the UI and bussiness separated... But this is not realy necesary because we are talking about a desktop app.

And at the other hand we have a Windows 8 App approach, with the benefits of a pure "touch-first" app. But what makes me feel unconfortable with it is the fear of that it can turn in a "code hell", like i said before, because Javascript is not the most organized of the languages (inspite the efforts of WinJS).

So, i would love to hear from people who has some Windows 8 HTML/Javascript experience if this kind of application is affordable with that technology or if it would be better to go for a server-client model.

Thanks for your advices!

**EDIT:**

Some more info:

It is a Windows desktop app, we don´t need to deploy it in any other platform, including Windows Phone.
Netlinx is a propietary programming language of AMX. It is a modular low level language.
A realy simplified example of how we manage the communication protocols is as follow:

User pushes a button.

```
    /****** User UI *****/

//Receives button event
BUTTON_EVENT[UIdevice, buttonId]
{
push:
{
    send_command deviceController, "START_VIDEOCONFERENCE"
}
}

//The UI receives orders from the controller
DATA_EVENT[UIdevice]
{
string:
{
    ...
    if(data.text == "VIDEOCONFERENCE_STARTED")
        //Set the button state to ON
        on[UIdevice, buttonId]
}
}


/**** Videoconference controller ****/

//The controller receives orders from the UI
DATA_EVENT[deviceController]
{
command:
{
    ...
    if(data.text == "START_VIDEOCONFERENCE")
        send_string serialPort, "something_in_videoconference_protocol_to_start"
    ...
}
}

//The controller receives responses and asynchronous messages from the real device
DATA_EVENT[serialPort]
{
string:
{
    ...
    if(data.text == "VIDEOCONFERENCE_STARTED")
        //tell UIDevice to refresh button status
        send_string UIdevice, "VIDEOCONFERENCE_STARTED"
}
}
```

So, the application has two main parts:

The UI that handles all the touch panel events. Which also has to manage the received messages from the controller.

And the controller, which has to start and keep the communication with the real device through serial port, telnet sockets or whatever, and send/receive the commands to/from the device; commands thrown from the UI events. So, the controller has a background task to keep the conection with the device alive and to listen to its asynchronous messages, and foreground tasks to listen the UI orders to send the corresponding commands to the device.

Sorry for the loooooooooooong question, but i´m just trying to explain it the best i can. If there is something that needs more explanation, just tell me.

Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Your question is really too broad for StackOverflow. Do you have a question about specific capabilities for example? Is this a Windows only application? I've never heard of NetLinx so I can't compare it to JavaScript. JavaScript, when structured consistently with modern patterns can be as organized as well as many other programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And sorry for this kind of question... What i´m looking for is just the opinion of people who worked with Windows 8 App to just tell me "yes, it is affordable to develop such application in HTML/Javascript/WinRT" or "no, better think in another framework because Windows 8 app are focused on other kind of market". My intention is not to start a debate or something similar. I´ll edit my question and try to explain it better. Thanks.

Comment: Opinion questions are generally held/closed on StackOverflow. You could also consider WinRT and XAML/C# if you want a Windows only application. If you think cross-platform is interesting, then you'll likely want to do a web page (especially if you want to have a web server that is relaying the commands from the UI).

Answer (score 1):

A web app is going to allow you to more closely mirror the current system architecture. In most control systems (AMX, Crestron et al), the central controller handles all the core logic and device communication then the detached UI merely provides user input events as well as displaying feedback. This is extremely similar to what you will achieve with the web app server/client separation and should be relatively trivial to implement.

That being said, opting for a native app will enable the server side to be dropped, bringing down the overall system complexity. Depending on the device comms being used this may require some additional hardware (RS-232 to ethernet gateways etc) to ensure communication can be maintained with all devices. The dominant drawback to this approach is that your entire system will become ephemeral. That is, you no longer have a persistent component (the server side) which is tracking all of the device states and is available to respond to device generated input. This may not have a massive impact for your use case, however a lot of these systems will be composed primarily of linked device behaviours (i.e. incoming videoconference call triggers display activation, signal routing, user alerts, or motion sensing from the IP cameras triggers changes to the lighting system etc). Additionally, when you are dealing with the user, you will need to first collect system state in order to show appropriate UI via polling devices which will impact latency of the UI. Depending on your device API's, some of this information may only revealed via asynchronous events during device operation. Assuming the host devices are maintaining connectivity to the various system components (not disconnecting from the network or being turned off) some of the above will be able to handled by background tasks in RT however there's limits on these in regards to allowable CPU usage, event scheduling and network usage. These are also split into two classes depending on if the app has been placed on the users lock screen. Further [details on this can be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx).